# HTTP POST: name/value pairs vs JSON string

Tags: android, ios, json, post

We are wondering whether it is better to place parameters of a server method call within name/value pairs in s post, or post a JSON string to be processed by the server. The problem is that in some cases, the length of the parameters varies, and it is easier to handle this with a JSON. Also because we are trying to foresee the case in which our app users using these methods grows a lot and performance becomes an issue.

Which way do you think is the best choice? Is there any other suggestion?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to post a JSON. You can pass them in HTTP body and thereby give it some security and invisibility.

And JSON string can be even passed as a url parameter if u want.